Input field onChange event in whatsapp flow?
I am building a WhatsApp flow in Meta's official WhatsApp business. Can we capture the input onChange event in the endpoint server? I want to display the embeddedLink only if a user enter the value in the input.
Any other solution to achieve this?
Also, I want to validate the input field with regex. Can we do this?

The TextInput component does not support an on-change event to send data to the endpoint server.
However, if you just want to hide/show a component if the user enters any value, you can use a conditional "If" component to achieve that as the example below.
JSON example
{
    "version": "5.0",
    "routing_model": {},
    "screens": [
        {
            "id": "WELCOME_SCREEN",
            "title": "Welcome",
            "terminal": true,
            "success": true,
            "layout": {
                "type": "SingleColumnLayout",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "type": "Form",
                        "name": "form",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextInput",
                                "label": "Email Input",
                                "input-type": "email",
                                "name": "email"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "If",
                                "condition": "${form.email} != ''",
                                "then": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "RadioButtonsGroup",
                                        "name": "notify",
                                        "label": "Notify by email",
                                        "data-source": [
                                            {
                                                "id": "1",
                                                "title": "Yes"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "id": "2",
                                                "title": "No"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Footer",
                        "label": "Complete",
                        "on-click-action": {
                            "name": "complete",
                            "payload": {}
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}



Can we check regex here?
